# Elementtree dump giving wrong answer

Tags: python, elementtree, xml.etree

```
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, dump

listing = Element("COMPUTERLISTING")
print "STARTING_WITH:", dump(listing),"ENDS_WITH."

This outputs...
STARTING_WITH:<COMPUTERLISTING />
None ENDS_WITH.

I thought it should be...
STARTING_WITH:<COMPUTERLISTING></COMPUTERLISTING> 
ENDS_WITH.
```

I don't get it though I am both ill and tired today. The unmatched tags are corrected once I start adding elements so it's not a showstopper as such but the phantom None remains whatever I do. What gives? I've left the imports in just in case there's something wrong with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `dump` should only be used for debugging. Also, you should try to avoid mixing the `lxml` and `xml` libraries, even if they are quite similar. To answer your question, a tag with no content is generally written like this:

```
<COMPUTERLISTING />
```

This is the equivalent of `<COMPUTERLISTING></COMPUTERLISTING>`.

You are getting `None` because `ElementTree.dump` writes to `sys.stdout` instead of to a file. When you print the output of `sys.stdout`, you are also printing the return value of `sys.stdout` (which is `None`):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> listing = etree.Element("COMPUTERLISTING")
>>> etree.dump(listing)  # returns normal sys.stdout output when you do not print
<COMPUTERLISTING>test</COMPUTERLISTING>
>>> print etree.dump(listing)  # now also prints the None returned by sys.stdout
<COMPUTERLISTING>test</COMPUTERLISTING>
None
```

For a cleaner approach, you can do this instead:

```
>>> print etree.tostring(listing)
<COMPUTERLISTING/>
```

Or to use something similar to the string you were printing earlier (only with text):

```
>>> listing.text = 'test'
>>> print "STARTING_WITH:", etree.tostring(listing), "ENDS_WITH."  # now with text
STARTING_WITH: <COMPUTERLISTING>test</COMPUTERLISTING> ENDS_WITH.
```